# Features Required to Import Personal Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, solution-package, export, import, move

I was working on a personal SP site as a development environment and now I am ready to move to the actual site. I exported the personal site into a .wsp file, uploaded it to the new site, and activated it. However, when I tried to make a new site from the template, it said that I needed to activate some features (which I can't find in the feature list of the source or target site).

[image]

Does anyone know how I can activate these features on the target site and if it is safe to do so? Alternatively, can I remove some of these features from my current site without breaking it? A lot of these seem to be social features associated with the fact that I was using a personal site, and I don't think I actually use the social features. Any combination of this that lets me move the site without breaking things would be useful.

UPDATE: 
Very unfortunate news. I have O365 plan P1 and based on this: (http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/193539.aspx) that means I cannot connect to the site with Windows PowerShell. Hopefully there is some way to remove the features without it...any help greatly appreciated...

Comment: Personal Site is not the correct place to create a template. Theses feature in question are specific to my sites and hence they are not available in normal sites. I would suggest you recreate the site using a Team Site/Other template and then export it as a WSP.

Comment: Okay, but since I've already put a couple months into developing the site, is there any way I can save my work? I didn't know this wasn't proper when I started but I understand this now. Can I maybe convert my current site to a team site then export it?

Comment: Nope. You best option is to create a blank site and then save the libraries as templates and then create those in the blank site. Once completed, you can export the site as template.

Comment: That is very poor solution unfortunately. When the export failed, I first started trying to do exactly that. Then there were issues with the lists because it disallowed importing any lists with lookups (almost all of them). That didn't even account for the fact that absolutely none of the settings, forms or workflows were saved. Is everything really completely lost? Do I really have to start over completely?

Comment: Ok another option is to create a site using your template under the personal site. Then deactivate mysite features (not sure if you need to use Powershell for SP Online) and then create a new template using that.

Comment: Alright, I'll try that. With any luck it will work. Thanks a lot!